# Partial Derivatives of $F(x,y,z) = \log(z + \sin(y^2 -x))$

Tags: partial-derivative

Partial derivatives with respect to $x$, $y$ and $z$.

Thank you!

Comment: So far I got z+sin(y^2-x)^-1 * 1-cos(y^2-x).

Comment: I have to find the gradient f(P) where P=(1,-1,1). I wanted to check my work with all the required partial derivatives. @NicholasStull

Comment: Fair enough.  I was just curious of what you had tried so far.  If you hold $x$, $y$ constant, then you will get
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{z+\sin(y^2-x)}$$
using the chain rule, and the other partial derivatives are computed similarly.

Comment: Thank you @NicholasStull. :)

Comment: I knew if I got one right I got them all.

Answer (score 0):

If you calculate $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}$, that means you hold $y$ and $z$ fixed. So: $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \dfrac{-cos(y^2 - x)}{z + sin(y^2 - x)}$

$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y} = \dfrac{2y \cdot cos(y^2 - x)}{z + sin(y^2 - x)}$

$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial z} = \dfrac{1}{z + sin(y^2 - x)}$